# Position sticky is not working on the IOS devices or iPhone device

Tags: html, css

I have tried and use the `position: sticky` code, but this is not working on the IOS device. It's working on the web and android devices. And I have checked to inspect the browser, I got the `position: -webkit-sticky;` property shows invalid.

I want to while the user scrolls the webpage then It will be stop or fixed on the TOP.

```css
.header1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9997;
}
```

```html
<div class="header1"> Here some content related to the header section.... </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `sticky` depends on the container element. We need to see more of your HTML and CSS.

Comment: You're definitely using the correct syntax for Safari/iOS...I'm not sure, Apple just tends to be buggy with this sort of thing.

Comment: How I can show you because they're a lot of code and content is showing dynamically from the database.

Comment: You can copy the rendered HTML from the page source and trim it down to the most minimal example. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).